# aggregate function 'count' not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using mySQL to query a mock university database. This is for a class so. The query I am trying to make is to this question:

> Find the names and ids of the students who have taken exactly one
>   course in the Spring 2010 semester.

schema tables:

*student(id, name, dept_name, total_cred)*

*takes(id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)*

I can query the schema for all students who took classes in Spring of 2010 no problem. But where I run into trouble is the 'exactly one class' part.

```
select distinct s.id, name
from student s join takes
where semester = 'Spring' and
    year = 2010;
```

I thought I would use a set operator like `not in` to compare that result to another that returns the number of classes taken by each student:

```
select distinct count(s.id) num_classes, name
from student s join takes
where semester = 'Spring' and
    year = 2010
group by name
```

The problem is that when I run this query it returns the count of 8 for each name. But I have no idea where it is getting that number because there is nothing that occurs exactly 8 times.

**My question(s):**

*1) am I going about this the right way?*

*2) If so what am I doing wrong to make the count return that way?*

Comment: 1) no; 2) `select name, count(*),  ..... group by name having count(*)=1`

Comment: One of the issues:  missing the join key `ON s.id = takes.id`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select s.id, s.name
from student s join takes t on s.id = t.id
where t.semester = 'Spring' and
    t.year = 2010
group by s.id, s.name
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you this definitely worked. I actually ended up with the same result after trying to do it my original way some more but this is far more effecient

Comment: @RileyHughes - Trying to do it your way is definitely the best way to learn.